# Channels tab is missing in video sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor, blender-osm

I am on Ubuntu LTS 20.04, and here is my blender version which i think is latest.
[image: About]

for some reason I am not able to get channels tab at the top left of video sequencer (there(mouse arrow) is not that tiny arrow to toggle the channels tab)
[image: Video sequencer]

Comment: I don't know the Linux versions of Blender, but Blender 3.0.1 is a _very_ old version! The current LTS (Long Term Support) version of Blender is 3.6.10 and the latest version is 4.0.2! [This](https://www.blender.org/download/) is the download page with links to Linux and LTS versions.

Comment: The manual from v3.0 doesn't seem different from here, so i reckon that an update would already be a big step forward. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/sequencer.html

Comment: Thanks to all I just updated it and it is working.